# Is there any Gson similar libraries for Python

Tags: python, json, gson

I am new to python .I was trying to create json responses for my android app. I was wondering if there is any library similar to GSON for python.

http://nullege.com/codes/search/com.google.gson.Gson
at this link i saw Gson the usage.

Can anyone please tell me if there is GSON libary for python , or any other similar library. Also if there is any please guide me to integrated it in the code.

Comment: [You do not need a library.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (Also, library remommendations are off-topic for SO)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Pykson, JSON Serializer and Deserializer for Python](https://github.com/sinarezaei/pykson) which is somehow like Gson. It supports lists of objects and serialization names.

Simply define your object model as `JsonObject`, and use `Pykson` to convert it back and forth to JSON.

```
class Student(JsonObject):
    first_name = StringField(serialized_name="fn")
    last_name = StringField(serialized_name="ln")
    age = IntegerField(serialized_name="a")

json_text = '{"fn":"John", "ln":"Smith", "a": 25}'
student = Pykson.from_json(json_text, Student)

student_json = Pykson.to_json(student)
assert (json_text == student_json)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jsonic](https://github.com/OrrBin/Jsonic) library.

Jsonic is a lightweight utility for serializing/deserializing python objects to/from JSON.

Example:

```
from jsonic import serialize, deserialize

class User(Serializable):
    def __init__(self, user_id: str, birth_time: datetime):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.birth_time = birth_time
   
user = User('id1', datetime(2020,10,11))      
obj = serialize(user) # {'user_id': 'id1', 'birth_time': {'datetime': '2020-10-11 00:00:00', '_serialized_type': 'datetime'}, '_serialized_type': 'User'}
new_user : User = deserialize(obj) # new_user is a new instance of user with same attributes
```

Jsonic has some nifty features:

1. You can serialize objects of types that are not extending `Serializable`.
   This can come handy when you need to serialize objects of
   third party library classes.
2. Support for custom serializers and deserializers
3. Serializing into JSON string or python dict
4. Transient class attributes
5. Supports both serialization of private fields or leave them out of the
   serialization process.

Full disclosure: I'm the creator of Jsonic

Answer (score 0):

You can use BSON:

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/index.html

Think of BSON as "binary JSON", meaning both:

- It's output is not simple ASCII (as JSON is)
- It has support for arbitrary byte strings (aka "Binary" is a native datatype)

In addition, it natively supports:

- datetime objects
- ObjectId objects

BSON is the "native" object marshaling technique of MongoDb.  So it is an object type that you get access to with the "pymongo" library.  You can load pymongo and not use it for MongoDb, and just use the BSON portion.

We use BSON to marshal long arrays of floating point numbers, for which JSON is an awful choice.  This is useful over raw TCP sockets, or other transports that send "byte blobs" as their payload, such as RabbitMQ messages.